# How can i modify the mongodb query to suit the collection structure

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and have  collection in the below format .

```
 db.options.find({ "undersymbol" : "UBSC"}).pretty()
{

        "finalsymbol" : "UBSC",
        "option_exp" : [
                {
                        "expiration_dt" : "2015-01-17",
                        "days_to_expire" : 638,
                        "low_strike" : 120,
                        "high_strike" : 190,
                        "no_of_strikes" : 86,
                        "options" : [
                                {
                                        "strikeprice" : "120.0",
                                        "chain_type" : "call",
                                        "symbol" : "UBSC"

                                }
              ]
                     },

          "expiration_dt" : "2015-01-18",
                        "days_to_expire" : 656,
                        "low_strike" : 34,
                        "high_strike" : 455,
                        "no_of_strikes" : 67,
                        "options" : [
                                {
                                        "strikeprice" : "420.0",
                                        "chain_type" : "call",
                                        "symbol" : "UBSC"

                                }
              ]
                     }


                }
        ]
}
```

Right now I am using the folllowing query to extract the Data from my collection

```
           BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("finalsymbol", "UBSC");
        OptionsData ocd = (OptionsData) coll.findOne(query);
```

The query that is being formed is

```
{ "finalsymbol" : "UBSC"}
```

Is it possible to that can i include the `expiration_dt` also along with `finalsymbol` in the query , so that the performance will be increased ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you just need to add a compound index, and to modify your query:

```
db.options.ensureIndex({finalsymbol:1,expiration_dt:1});
```

Modify your Java code as follows:

```
BasicDBObject query= new BasicDBObject("finalsymbol", "UBSC")
                              .append("expiration_dt":"2015-01-18");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search by expiration date, just add another field to the query calling `put` (wasn't it `append` by the way?) again.
If you need performances, define an index on the field you're using to query the collection.